# Default date field values like "today +10 hours 30 minutes"

Tags: 7, datetime

I have a date_field Date (ISO format) as a Pop-up calendar. I would like to have it as a default value: today 10:30
In php the

```
strtotime("today +10 hours 30 minutes")
```

serves me well. Also

```
strtotime("today 10:30 am")
```

If I put it in the "Relative default value" field, the time gets not parsed. It is always the current time.

```
strtotime("noon")
```

or

`strtotime("midnight")`

has the same effect. Bug? How to get the default date to "today 10:30 am"?

Comment: Are you putting "strtotime("today +10 hours 30 minutes")" or just "+10 hours 30 minutes".  I'm fairly certain that the second is what you want.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't be clear enough. With the PHP function I get the working syntax. In the Date field I put ""today 10:30 am". Not working. I will post a bug report.

Comment: Is this a custom form built with the form api or a date popup field added to an entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been fixed, YAY!
http://drupal.org/node/1302212

Answer (score 4):

The best way to control the default output of form elements is through the drupal [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7).

You have two scenarios:

1. If you created the form with the form api and have a date popup in your form, you can use the method described in [this post](http://drupal.org/node/292667) to set the #default_format of the #default_value of the form element.
2. If you didn't create the date popup in the form element with the form api, meaning you added it as a field to an entity through site configuration, you can still make a small custom module solution.  Make a custom module and implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), find the field in question and set the #default_value using the method mentioned in #1

Answer (score 1):

This will surely work.

```
$form['date'] = array(
  '#type'=>'date_popup',
  '#date_format'=>'d-m-y',
  '#default_value' =>date('Y-m-d'),
  '#date_type' => DATE_DATETIME,
  '#date_timezone' => date_default_timezone(),
  '#date_format' => 'm/d/Y',
  '#prefix' => '<td>',
  '#suffix' => '</td></tr></table>',
  '#size'=>20,
);
```