# How to remove the Day field from a Date?

Tags: webforms, datetime

I want to remove the *day* field from a Date dropdown of a webform. How to do that? I tried with `hook_form_alter()` without success. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: can you post the code you tried, also you have to make sure to add a day before saving, you can use a custom validate function to handle this.

Comment: Finally I solved this creating two separate fields without the day.Also thanks for your answer.

Comment: @sokratis please either post your solution as an answer to the question and mark it accepted, or vote to close/delete your question

Comment: You can use the same concepts mentioned in my answer to this question:

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12510/default-date-field-values-like-today-10-hours-30-minutes/12940#12940

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no coding-free way to achieve this but to create a separate Number-type field for year and month.